# PHP include link to online file

Tags: php, include

Can I use include (or something similar) to get functions (or something else) from an online file?

Something like this:

```
include 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask.php';
```

Comment: No. For including a file you have to use the absolute path other than the web path

Comment: You can only include files that are under the same server root.

Comment: Did you try it? Didn't work eh? There you go ;-) You could probably get away with using an iframe; I said "probably" unless they're blocking such requests as many do. Question is: *"why?"* and why the Stack link, or did you mean to use a generic "example.com/file.php"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Simple Answer:** No

**Elaborating:**
If you use `http` or `https` inside your file path, you are literally telling your code to include a file that is on the internet and to use the HTTP / HTTPS protocol in that process.

As you probably know, php code is executed on the server and is never displayed to users online, but rather the output of the php is displayed.

For that reason, you won't be able to gain access to your php functions while being a user from online *(because that is how you will be perceived with the previous method)*.

What you should do is either use `relative paths` or `absolute paths` to include php scripts with functions **on the same server**. Here is some php documentation if you want to read a bit more on how to format the path: [PHP DOC](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path)

Answer (score 0):

The short answer as Webeng said NO in common case.

However, it should depend on your PHP version and the configuration of your local devices. If you activate the option "allow_url_include" (deprecated since 7.4+), it can work.

See the [doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-include)